# How to close native browser in Telegram programmatically?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I need close browser after some user actions what was opened by link click in Telegram chat. How to do this **programmatically** if it's possible?

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: @ihoru,    
There some bots with OAuth support. "@YouTube" bot for example. When I click link to auth it opens in the In-App browser by default. Then browser closes after I click "Submit" in authorization form. How it closes in this case?

Comment: You may try to do this with JavaScript code: `window.close();`

Comment: `window.close()` does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by redirecting the browser to a `telegram.me` link.

```
window.location.href = "https://telegram.me/yourbot"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the first answer is not relevant anymore.
This helped me:

```
window.location.href = "tg:resolve";
```

Comment: how can you tell?